# Grails codenarc plugin for Grails 1.3.9

Tags: grails, plugins, codenarc

Searching the plugin site and other resources I could not find which plugin version must I install for my Grails version. Can someone help me out?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Hi @Jacob could you please share me if you find the solution for it. I too searching for an old version of codenarc which will support Grails 1.3.7 but I did not get any help online and codenarc documentation also.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the codenarc plugin a Grails 1.X app by running the following command:

```
grails install-plugin codenarc
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Hi @Jacob could you please share me if you find the solution for it. I too searching for an old version of codenarc which will support Grails 1.3.7 but I did not get any help online and codenarc documentation also.